# Why is the compiler thinking this constructor overload resolution is ambiguous?

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion

I'm missing why the compiler (Visual Studio 2017) is thinking this semi-recursive overload resolution is ambiguous, and casting is required:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a) {}
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A a) {}
};

void func(B b) {}

void useCase()
{
    func((B)1);   // OK! So it "knows" how to convert from 1 to B 
    func(1);      // ERROR: why is it ambiguous to convert 1, when no alternative exists?
    func((int)1); // ERROR: why is it ambiguous to convert 1, when no alternative exists?
}
```

Error is:
error C2664: 'void func(B)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'B'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

I can work around this, and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'd love to know what's going on. ;)

Comment: At most, only one user-defined conversion will be applied by the compiler.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Neil is saying, the construction is not ambiguous at all, the actual error is "No constructor could take the source type"

Comment: the "ambiguous" part of your error message misleading [gccs error is more clear](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VPM0C193tdFf85lZ)